# How to convert ISO-8859-1 to UTF-8 in node.js from readfile buffer

Tags: node.js, utf-8

as per title, I am trying to parse a txt encoded in ISO-8859-1 to put data into a DB. I do need that these data is converted into UTF-8 before. This is due to the fact that some special character, particularly uppercase accented characters, are shown as question mark in the DB and in front-end consequently.

The code I am using is:

```
this.fs.readFile(fileName, null, function(err, buff){
                    if (err) {
                        self.openFiles();
                    } else {

                        var data = buff.toString('UTF-8');
                        self.parseNews(data, fileName);                             
                    }
                });
```

I know there are similar questions on SO, but none helped me... 
Could you help me in some way or address to a solution?

Thanks!
Fabio

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to specify the input encoding. Assuming that `this.fs.readFile` is the same as [`fs.readFile`](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_readfile_file_options_callback):

```
this.fs.readFile(fileName, { encoding : 'latin1' }, function(err, buff) {
  ...
  var data = buff.toString(); // no need to specify encoding here
});
```

Comment: Hi, I am testing your solution, waiting for news to enter. in the meanwhile may I ask you why latin1 and not ISO-8859-1 which is the encoding of files which are parsed and not UTF-8 which is the encoding destination?

Comment: Wow it is working man! How could latin1 help? i am very curious. A big big big thank you for your support

Comment: `ISO-8859-1` is the same as `latin1`, but I'm not sure if Node.js knows it by that first name. You have to tell Node that the file contains text encoded in that format (the input encoding). If you don't specify it, Node will assume that the file contains UTF-8 encoded text. For the rest (like `buff.toString()`), Node will use the default (which is `utf-8`).

Comment: I am not sure if latin1 contains greek characters, ISO-8859-1 does. So no, for me it is not working.

Comment: @Jonas `latin1` is equivalent to ISO-8859-1, according to the [Node.js docs](https://nodejs.org/api/buffer.html#buffers-and-character-encodings). I think that for Greek you need [ISO-8859-7](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-7).